# Effect of batch normalization after input layer on model performance

Tags: r, model, overfitting, keras, batch-normalization

I built a ML model with high accuracy using

```
model <- keras_model_sequential(input_shape=input_shape) %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dense(units=128,activation='relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dense(units=64, activation='relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dense(units=32, activation='relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dense(units=16, activation='relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dense(units=8, activation='relu') %>%
    layer_batch_normalization() %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')

model %>% compile(
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer ='adam',
    metrics = list('accuracy'))
```

I created a plot to see if the model performs well on unknown test data:

[image]

Next, I wanted to see what happens if I remove the first batch normalization layer after the input layer. Could you help me to interpret this result? Would you expect it?

[image]

Comment: Compare these results to scaling the data before sending it to the neural network.